# Matplotlib external axes ruin subplot layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, multiple-axes

I would like to plot a figure with 3 subplots. The middle one has 3 different x-axes, one of which is detached and placed below the subplot. When I use [`Gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) for the layout the plot areas are spaced equidistantly, but the padding between the axes labels of different subplots is hugely different:
[image]
Here is the code to reproduce the figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.375, 6.5))
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig)

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
ax0.set_xlabel('x label 0')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1])
ax1.set_xlabel('x label 1a')
secax1 = ax1.twiny()
secax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
secax1.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
secax1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 40))
secax1.set_xlabel('x label 1b')
thax1 = ax1.twiny()
thax1.set_xlabel('x label 1c')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2])
ax2.set_xlabel('x label 2a')
ax2.set_ylabel('y label 2')
secax2 = ax2.twiny()
secax2.set_xlabel('x label 2b')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('3 subplots same size.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

I'm looking for a way to either make the spacing between the *complete* subfigures equal, with everything like the additional axes and their labels. Or a way to manually shift the subplots within the grid. The subplots don't need to maintain the same size.

I tried changing the `height_ratios` as

```
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, figure=fig, height_ratios=[1, 1.5, 1])
```

but it doesn't affect the spaces between the plots.
[image]

Comment: Not sure it works, but did you try constrained_layout instead of tight_layout?

Comment: @JodyKlymak Nice, this takes care of this issue automatically. I hope it will soon be out of the [experimental phase](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html?highlight=constrained_layout#codecell1:~:text=Warning,ax.set_position()%20in%20your%20code%20with%20constrained_layout%3DFalse.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing is where `constrained_layout` does better than `tight_layout`.  `tight_layout` only allows one margin size, so makes lots of room between the rows of subplots.  `constrained_layout` keeps one upper and lower margin per row of the gridspec.

Yes, constrained_layout is marked experimental.  That is so its behaviour can be changed without warning.  But the API is not likely to change.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig, (ax0, ax1, ax2)  = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(3.375, 6.5), 
                                   constrained_layout=True)

ax0.set_xlabel('x label 0')

ax1.set_xlabel('x label 1a')
secax1 = ax1.twiny()
secax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
secax1.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
secax1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 40))
secax1.set_xlabel('x label 1b')
thax1 = ax1.twiny()
thax1.set_xlabel('x label 1c')

ax2.set_xlabel('x label 2a')
ax2.set_ylabel('y label 2')
secax2 = ax2.twiny()
secax2.set_xlabel('x label 2b')
```

[image: CLversion]

Answer (score 1):

You could use plt.subplots and put invisiable "gap plots" in between your real plots then you can adjust the gaps by changing the height_ratios of the gap plots

```
f, (ax0, gap1, ax1, gap2, ax2) = plt.subplots(5, 1,figsize=(3.375,8), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1,1,1,1.75,1]})


gap1.axis('off')# Make the gap plots invisable
gap2.axis('off')# Make the gap plots invisable

#ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
ax0.set_xlabel('x label 0')

#ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2])
ax1.set_xlabel('x label 1a')
secax1 = ax1.twiny()
secax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
secax1.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
secax1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 40))
secax1.set_xlabel('x label 1b')
thax1 = ax1.twiny()
thax1.set_xlabel('x label 1c')

#ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[5])
ax2.set_xlabel('x label 2a')
ax2.set_ylabel('y label 2')
secax2 = ax2.twiny()
secax2.set_xlabel('x label 2b')
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this works. With the `height_ratio` one can manually shift the figures around. If the y-axis label should not be clipped one needs to enable the tight_layout again, which let's you change the vertical distance between the subplots. I get a good layout if I add `plt.tight_layout(h_pad=-8.0)` after the rest. But admittedly, the solution with `constrained_layout` is more convenient.